# Is it possible to view data stored in Core Data on a development iphone?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data

Is there a way to grab/view the coredata db (sqlite store) off of the development iphone through xcode or some other means? While I've been able to inspect the db created through the simulator on my mac, I'd like to validate what's on the actual phone (without having to create debugging views in the app, etc.) as i'm reading sensor data and storing it in coredata.

Comment: Do not getting it. What you want to do? You want SQLite database to inspect for that?

Comment: No, I just want to get a copy of the sqlite db that's on the iphone being used for development - want to validate the data being stored via coredata.  I think Darren's suggestion below is what I'm looking for... will post feedback once I've confirmed

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can using Xcode organizer.
Select you phone, then app, and you can export and import files from/to the sandbox
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/copy_app_data_from_sandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010392-CH14-SW1

Comment: I've used this method before to extract a used SQLite db, changed stuff, then put it back.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is an official way to do this but I use a piece of software called iExplorer formerly iPhone Explorer. http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/

You can then browse the Apps directory similar to the simulator and find your app and goto the documents directory and grab the sqlite file.

Hope this helps